# Purpose of a | (a ^ a)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am reading some 3rd party verilog code for synchronizer circuits (clock domain crossing). I see many statements that look like this:

```
...
input [width-1:0] a;

wire [width-1:0] sync_data;

assign sync_data = a | (a ^ a);
...
// Then sync_data goes into a D-Flip-flop for synchronization.
```

This code is used in simulation mode. I don't see the point of adding *a^a* since that equals **0**. Can anyone think of a reason why this would be useful/needed? Thanks.

Comment: could be a leftover from some fine tuning of  a particular ancient synthesis engine.  Does not make any sense otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point either. Any halfway competent synthesis tools will optimize that logic, making `sync_data` equivalent to `a`.

This might have been an attempt to apply a small delay to the `sync_data` signal by inserting some logic into the path, but it won't work.